# Incrementing a pointer by 1 in an array of words: loading a word from half way between two words?

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-16, masm

Consider the code below. If incrementing `SI` by 2 gives me the 2nd element of the array, what exactly would incrementing `SI` by 1 give me?

```
.data  
var dw 1,2,3,4  
.code  
LEA SI,VAR  
MOV AX,[SI]  
INC SI  
MOV AX,[SI]
```

Comment: Hint: write out the memory contents of `var`, byte by byte.  Keep in mind that x86 is little-endian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Statement `var dw 1,2,3,4` tells the assembler to statically define eight bytes in memory at the beginning of `.data` segment. Layout of the data bytes will be

```
|01|00|02|00|03|00|04|00|
```

and the first `MOV AX,[SI]` will load AL with 01 and AH with 00.
When you increment SI only by 1, the next `MOV AX,[SI]` will load AL with 00 and AH with 02.
If you want to keep loading AX with the whole 16bit words, increment SI by 2 (`ADD SI,2`).

You could also replace both `MOV AX,[SI]` and `ADD SI,2` with one single instruction [LODSW](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lods:lodsb:lodsw:lodsd:lodsq) which does the same and occupies only one byte instead of five. In this case you should be sure to have the Direction flag reset (using the instruction [CLD](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cld) in the beginning of your program).

Comment: Nitpick: `lodsw` doesn't alter the flags like `add` does.

Comment: @ecm Indeed, and replacing `ADD SI,2` with `INC SI` + `INC SI` doesn't alter CF like `ADD` does :-)

Comment: **Flags-wise** this `LODSW` would be equivalent to `MOV AX, [SI]` `LEA SI, [SI+2]`